# Qt, tcp/ip communication checksum

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

I am writing a data display program where I receive the data through a serial port. The listener is written by others and it is quite complex. Now I need to transfer the received data to another program/pc. So I am thinking of the standard tcp communication from Qt.
Is there any class that come along with the tcp classes that does job like checksum?
If I am transmitting an array of 10 doubles each time but at high frequency. How could I write a client that received all the data correctly without writing those complex algorithms to check the validity of received data bytes?

Comment: Integrity checks are built into TCP/IP. TCP guarantees that the data, if it is received at all, is intact and in order.

Comment: So I just read 10 doubles each time? But doesn't this mean that once the data is somehow shifted(like if there are some data left in the socket) I will never get it right again?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty. What do you mean "shifted"? Shifted how, where and by whom?

Comment: AFAIK, tcp chop the datastream into packets? So, I just receive all the packet continuously and decode them once every 8*10 bytes(10 doubles)? I am new to socket programming still confused about the text book's saying...

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP includes these checks as part of the protocol itself. This includes guarantees for data integrity, as well as the correct re-assembly of data (i.e it will definitely be in the same order). You mentioned that TCP chops the datastream into packets; this is true, but it will re-assemble the packets in the correct order on the receiving end, or request a re-transmission if it needs to do so. All of this is taken care of by the Qt networking classes.

Comment: So, it is safe to always read every 10 doubles received through the tcp socket?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot assume that the values will be received all at once. For an example on how to handle something like this, I'd suggest looking at the Qt Fortune Server example http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html. In the example, it shows how to receive text, but you can easily change that to a QByteArray or something similar.